# Socket.io swift compiler error

Tags: swift, socket.io

I am trying to use `socket.io` in swift: [this library](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift). I copied `SocketIOClientSwift` folder to my project folder, but I am getting these errors:

[image]

How do I fix these errors?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Xcode 7 GM, You can download that from the xcode developer